# Search WooCommerce orders admin for custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, custom-fields

Probably a very simple question but it leaves me clueless..

On the web if found the following code for searching a custom field on the order page. What If I wanted to scope another field?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total' );
    function woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total( $search_fields ) {
       $search_fields[] = 'woochimp_field';
       return $search_fields;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$search_fields[]` Is an Array as it turns out. Every time you use `$search_fields[] = 'woochimp_field';` you add to the array and makes you able to search more custom fields.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total' );
   function woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total( $search_fields ) {
       $search_fields[] = 'woochimp_field';
       $search_fields[] = 'woochimp_field_2';    //example
       return $search_fields;
}
```